# Nuxt + Vuex + Computed Property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am currently trying Nuxt.js with Vuex. And I Built a simple form, where I have an email field, a password field and a button.

All my state, mutations and actions are working as they should be. But When I created a computed property just to validate the password, I always have an error with an if statement to validate length of the password.

My Vuex state looks like this:

```
export default () => ({
// Register Init States
  registerEmail: null,
  registerPassword: null,
})
```

My mutation:

```
export default {
  setRegisterEmail(state, registerEmail) {
    state.registerEmail = registerEmail
  },
  setRegisterPassword(state, registerPassword) {
    state.registerPassword = registerPassword
  },
}
```

My template:

```
            <vs-input
              :value="registerPassword"
              label="Password"
              primary
              type="password"
              :progress="getProgress"
              :visible-password="hasVisiblePassword"
              icon-after
              @input="setRegisterPassword"
              @click-icon="hasVisiblePassword = !hasVisiblePassword"
            >
              <template #icon>
                <i v-if="!hasVisiblePassword" class="bx bx-show-alt"></i>
                <i v-else class="bx bx-hide"></i>
              </template>

              <template v-if="getProgress == 100" #message-success
                >Secure password</template
              >
            </vs-input>
```

My Computed property:

```
getProgress() {
      let progress = 0
      // at least one number
      if (/\d/.test(this.$store.state.auth.registerPassword)) {
        progress += 30
      }
      // at least one capital letter
      if (/(.*[A-Z].*)/.test(this.$store.state.auth.registerPassword)) {
        progress += 20
      }
      // at least a lowercase
      if (/(.*[a-z].*)/.test(this.$store.state.auth.registerPassword)) {
        progress += 25
      }
      // more than 8 digits
      if (this.$store.state.auth.registerPassword === null) {
        progress += 0
      } else if (this.$store.state.auth.registerPassword.length >= 8) {
        progress += 25
      }
      return progress
    },
```

So because the password init state is null, there should be no progress, but as I type the password, it should to the else if and verify the number of chars.

But when I type the password, the input and my state only keeps the last letter I typed.

Imagine that I typed "overflow", my state password would only have "w". And if I remove the password validation length, my state looks like this "overflow".

Am I doing something wrong? I hope I was clear  Because I am so confused right now.

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking the length of the `this.value` ? that's the password you were doing all the check against before.

Comment: sorry I updated the question. I forgot to exchange this.value by this.$store.state.auth.registerPassword.

Comment: Is the problem with how you are updating the `registerPassword` state value? Can you add that code as well?

Comment: @Dylan. I updated again and added my Mutations code.

Comment: Thanks, one last thing, can you add the code where you are calling `setRegisterPassword()`.

Comment: @Dylan. Bellow my mutations code. You will have my template code for that specific input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is being caused when you call `setRegisterPassword` in the template. That input event is only returning the last input character. You can add a handler to update that value properly. One option is to use a local data property as a `v-model` binding and then `setRegisterPassword` to that value in the input handler.

```
            <vs-input
              v-model="localPassword"
              label="Password"
              primary
              type="password"
              :progress="getProgress"
              :visible-password="hasVisiblePassword"
              icon-after
              @input="handleRegisterPassword"
              @click-icon="hasVisiblePassword = !hasVisiblePassword"
            >
```

and in your

```js
data(){
 return {
   localPassword:''
 }
},
methods: {
  handleRegisterPassword() {
    this.setRegisterPassword(this.localPassword);
  }
}
```

Note: I sam not familiar with `vs-input` so your `:value` may work the same as `v-model` so you may be able to leave that as value.

Comment: But if I use v-model in my template won't it give problems? I followed what Vuex stated here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html.

Comment: Because I am accessing my vuex state, mutations and actions. And for that I am using mapState, mapMutations and mapActions. That's why I was using :value instead of v-model, and using @input  for my mutations.

Comment: Yes, you can not use v-model for the `registerPassword` state value, that is why I suggest you use a different variable from the component's data property, and set the vuex state in the handler

Comment: But if I use the handleRegisterPassword won't my registerPassword be " " (empty?)

Comment: Not if you bind the input to `localPassword`.